# Error occured when Previewing Mailables In The Browser in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to preview Mailables in the browser but I am getting this error.

```
Object of class App\Mail\ExamNotification could not be converted to string
```

I followed all instruction in https://laravel.com/docs/master/mail and cannot found what cause this error.

Here is my route file

```
Route::get('/mailable', function () {
    $parent = App\Parents::find(2);

    return new App\Mail\ExamNotification($parent);
});
```

Here is the contents of App\Mail\ExamNotification.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

use App\Parents;

class ExamNotification extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * The parent instance.
     *
     * @var Parent
     */
    public $parent;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Parents $parent)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;
    }


    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('donot-replay@example.com')
                    ->markdown('emails.exams.notification');
    }
}
```

And here is the contents of view file

```
@component('mail::message')
# Introduction
Parent Name is {{ $parent->name }}
The body of your message.

@component('mail::button', ['url' => ''])
Button Text
@endcomponent

Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

And please note that when i dd($this->parent) inside the constructor i am getting the correct query object. But i am unable to dd($this->parent); inside build function (ie same error mentioned above occurred).

Edited : please note that i am also able to send mail using this function inside my route file

```
Mail::to('app@example.com')->send(new App\Mail\ExamNotification($parent));
```

So also able to

```
dd(new App\Mail\ExamNotification($parent));
```

without any problem the output of above is

```
    ExamNotification {#664 ▼
  +parent: Parents {#687 ▶}
  +from: []
  +to: []
  +cc: []
  +bcc: []
  +replyTo: []
  +subject: null
  #markdown: null
  +view: null
  +textView: null
  +viewData: []
  +attachments: []
  +rawAttachments: []
  +callbacks: []
  +connection: null
  +queue: null
  +delay: null
}
```

and the output of dd($this->parent); inside constructor is

```
    Parents {#687 ▼
  #guard: "parent"
  #table: "parents"
  #dates: array:1 [▶]
  #fillable: array:7 [▶]
  #hidden: array:2 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:15 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "James Kurian"
  ]
  #original: array:15 [▶]
  #casts: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #events: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #forceDeleting: false
  #rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
  #forceDeleting: false
}
```

So it is very clear that the issue is only with previewing the mail and not with sending the mail.

Please tell me where i make the mistake and thanks in advance.

Comment: what's your "Parent->name" variable? is it a string.

Comment: @okante it just output the name of that parent

Comment: As I know, it seems you are trying to "echo" something that's not a string

Comment: Please update your question with the output of `dd($this->parent)`

Comment: @linktoahref i update the question. please take a look

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you're having this issue is because the ability to render Mailables was only introduced in Laravel 5.5.

You should be able to implement the functionality yourself though by adding to your `ExamNotification`:

```
public function render()
{
    $this->build();

    if ($this->markdown) {
        return $this->buildMarkdownView()['html'];
    }

     return view($this->buildView(), $this->buildViewData());
}
```

---

This you will need to update your Route to call the `render()` method:

```
Route::get('/mailable', function () {
    $parent = App\Parents::find(2);

    return (new App\Mail\ExamNotification($parent))->render();
});
```

I have only tested this with a couple of scenarios but it seems to work fine.